# PHP splitting a string

Tags: php, regex

So I have the following string:

```
{family:Open Sans,name:Open Sans,import_family:Open+Sans:300,300italic,regular,italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic,classname:opensans}
```

I'd like to "vectorize" it, so maybe it would look something like this:

```
XX['family'] = "Open Sans',
XX['name'] = 'Open Sans',
XX['import_family'] = 'Open+Sans:300,300italic,regular,italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic',
XX['classname'] = 'opensans';
```

Any ideas on how I could achieve this in PHP? It's getting on my nerves, been trying to work it out with regular expressions for the last couple of hours with no results so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you distinguish between the different meanings of `:` and commas? For example, `import_family` might also have the value `Open+Sans:300,300italic,regular,italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic,classname:opensans`.

Comment: Is the first string intended to be valid JSON?
is your "vectorized" output a string or a php array?

Comment: @Overv You can simply make it a prerequisite that keys are lower-case, and it's completely parsable.

Comment: @meagar That solves the problem of `Open+Sans`, but it doesn't solve the problem of the commas meaning different things. The `classname:opensans` string could be part of the list or a new key/value.

Comment: @Overv Yes it does. "Any lower-case token matching [a-z]+ followed by a colon is a key". Done. I'm not saying it's a *good* way of encoding data, but the data we've been given has no ambiguities in it.

Comment: That string should probably have newlines and that would make it easier.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's the issue, because there are additional commas in that string and I'm having a hard time exploding the string. It's not a JSON but rather a parsed string out of it.

Comment: string JSON parsing is fault syntax data {"key":"value"}

Comment: Sidenote, would like to read it only by these 4 values, as I have a list of 600 strings and they all have only these (family, name, import_family and classname)

Comment: @evergreen not really, this is it's output from google API so i guess that's not faulty at all.

Comment: [A quick fiddle](http://regex101.com/r/aS2cM6) `([^:,]+):(.+?)(?=,[^,]+:|$)`. Test it thoroughly before use on production. Of course, you need to match `{...}` first or trim them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple parser for this format you could use. It will handle all fields and values and return them as a key/value array. It assumes that the string starts and ends with curly braces and uses the `field:optional:optional,a,b,c` format.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    function parse($str) {
        $obj = [];

        $str = substr($str, 1, -1);
        $candidates = explode(',', $str);

        $lastKey = null;

        foreach ($candidates as $candidate) {
            if (strpos($candidate, ':')) {
                $parts = explode(':', $candidate);
                $key = $parts[0];
                $value = substr($candidate, strlen($key) + 1);

                $obj[$key] = $value;
                $lastKey = $key;
            } else {
                $obj[$lastKey] .= ',' . $candidate;
            }
        }

        return $obj;
    }

    $example = '{family:Open Sans,name:Open Sans,import_family:Open+Sans:300,300italic,regular,italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic,classname:opensans}';
    print_r(parse($example));
?>
```

Output from the example string you specified:

```
Array
(
    [family] => Open Sans
    [name] => Open Sans
    [import_family] => Open+Sans:300,300italic,regular,italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic
    [classname] => opensans
)
```

Comment: You're the best! I've removed the header and declared $obj as array();  and it works that great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$s = "{family:Open Sans,name:Open Sans,import_family:Open+Sans:300,300italic,regular,italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic,classname:opensans}";
$s = rtrim(ltrim($s, '{'), '}');

preg_match_all('#([^:,]+):((?:(?!(,[^:,]+:)).)*)#', $s, $matches);
$vector = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

**EDIT**

As [HamZa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401975/hamza) explains [here](http://regex101.com/r/aS2cM6), a shorter regular expression is:

```
([^:,]+):(.+?)(?=,[^,]+:|$)
```